# Qualifying criteria to an ATP tournament

Tags: tennis, tournaments, atp

How many ATP points, or what ATP ranking, does a player need to participate in the qualification of an ATP 250 tournament?

The rules do not seem clear on this point.

Answer (score 0):

There is no minimum ATP ranking requirement to sign up for an ATP tournament. A player simply needs to be a registered ATP Player Member.

ATP Circuit Regulations - Section 1.07

> 6. For entry into an ATP Tour or ATP Challenger Tour tournament, all players must
>    be an ATP Player Member (”Member”) or an ATP Registered Player. Wild cards
>    are exempt from this provision.

That being said, it's highly unlikely that a player with no ranking points would be selected as a participant over a player with any ranking points.